# Properly Merge of 2 or more Hashmaps with multiple values from each key

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I´m looking for a way to properly merge 2 or more hashmaps in 1, in this specific case i want to merge 2 or more hashmaps with many keys with him  respectives values in this case are more than 1. like (key(i), value1, value2, ... valueN )

My code:

```
int f =0;

while (f < Response.size()) {

map3.putAll(Response.get(f).getUsers());

f = f + 1;}
```

Where Response is the class where I´m saving the json and Users are the HashMap i define in the class , of course inside the Map Users  i have the getters to map values like users.getName, users.getDescription, users.getAge

code:

```
public class Response {

 private Map<String, Users> users = new LinkedHashMap<>();

 public Map<String, ProductsBean> getusers() {return users;}

  public static class Users {

        private String name;
        private String description;
        private String age;

      public String getName() {return name;}
      public String getDescription() {return description;}
      public String getAge() {return age;} }
```

I need TO merge all the maps coz I need to send in to Adapter.

Comment: Please clarify what are the types of the input maps and what type you expect the result map to have, both for keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I properly understand your code, as getUsers doesn't look like it will return a Map

However, I **can** help you merge two maps as follows:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // Create maps to combine
        Map<String, String> mapA = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> mapB = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // Create final map
        Map<String, List<String>> mapC = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // Add data to input mapA
        mapA.put("A", "value1");
        mapA.put("B", "value2");

        // Add data to input mapB
        mapB.put("C", "Happy");
        mapB.put("B", "Sad");

        // Fill results from mapA
        mapC = populateMapCWithMapContent(mapC, mapA);
        mapC = populateMapCWithMapContent(mapC, mapB);

        // Check Results
        assertEquals(2, mapA.size());
        assertEquals(2, mapB.size());
        assertEquals(3, mapC.size());

        // show results
        for (String key : mapC.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key=" + key);
            List<String> values = mapC.get(key);
            for (String value : values) {
                System.out.println("    Value = " + value);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Populate mapC with provided map Contents
     * 
     * @param mapC
     *            - resulting map
     * @param map
     *            - input data
     * @return mapC
     * 
     *         Note: this would work with a void, but I always feel that if mapC is
     *         changed, then mapC should be returned (To help readability). 
     */
    private Map<String, List<String>> populateMapCWithMapContent(Map<String, List<String>> mapC,
            Map<String, String> inputMap) {
        List<String> mapCValues;
        for (String key : inputMap.keySet()) {
        if (mapC.containsKey(key)) {
                mapCValues = mapC.get(key);
            } else {
                mapCValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            mapCValues.add(inputMap.get(key));
            mapC.put(key, mapCValues);
        }
        return mapC;
    }
}
```

Which provides the following results:

```
Key=A
    Value = value1
Key=B
    Value = value2 
    Value = Sad
Key=C 
    Value = Happy
```

Note that mapA and mapB just contains String values, but since the combined map (mapC) needs to hold multiple values for a single key, then I have used List. 
It would also be possible to include another map instead of a string. e.g.

```
Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> mapC = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: Hi, i have an JsonArray with many object inside response, but inside each object i have Users List that why i´m Mapping the Users object the problem is i need to consolidate all Users in One Map or List, example Object 1 (Users1) - Object 2 (Users 2) - ... ObjectN (Users N) and i need to consolidate all users in 1 Map considering that i have 1 key (user ID) and multiple values per key like Users attributes (id, Name, Age ...).